# The code do not fill json variable using httpclient.execute

Tags: android, url, http-post, ioexception

I am with a problem in my code . I tried many things in this code ,however it does not fix . In the end the error is described. The code do not have error of sintax, however when i run the code, the app does not work. So i debug and noticed that jsonResult  is null.

When i write in a new app with just main activity, the app works well.

**SelectActivityAnswer.java**

```
package com.example.test;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;





public  class SelectAnswerActivity extends Fragment  {
     final static String ARG_POSITION_ANSWER = "position";
     private String jsonResult;
     private String url = "http://myip/employee_details.php";
     private ListView listView;


     public SelectAnswerActivity() {
         // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses


     }



    //@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, null, 0, null, null);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_select_answer, container, false);

        accessWebService();


    //  selectListAns = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ans_list);
         // novo code abaixo
      //  ListAdapterAns adapterAns = new ListAdapterAns(this,toppings);
     //   selectListAns.setAdapter(adapterAns);
     //   selectListAns.setOnItemClickListener(new AnsItemClickListener());

        //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_select_answer, container, false);
        //int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        //String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        //int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                    //    "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
       // ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
      //  getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }

 // Async Task to access the web
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }



        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                //      "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ListDrwaer();
        }
    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        // passes values for the urls string array
        task.execute(new String[] { url });
    }

    // build hash set for list view
    public void ListDrwaer() {
        List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("employee name");
                String number = jsonChildNode.optString("employee no");
                String outPut = name + "-" + number;
                employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
            //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
                R.id.content_list_ans,
                new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "c", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
        HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
        return employeeNameNo;
    }

}
```

In this block code:

```
 // Async Task to access the web
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I dont know why, but when the line is running:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The code jump to line:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: and what it prints in catch? Add logcat output/crash here in your question!!

Comment: "http://myip/employee_details.php". First make sure if its a HTTPGet or HTTPPost. Then find out what parameters you need to send to the service for it to respond back. Also check if you need to add anything to the header

Comment: The code do not have error of sintax, however when i run the code, the app does not work. So i debug and noticed that jsonResult is null.

When i write in a new app with just main activity, the app works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
```

to

```
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-08"));
jsonResult = reader.readLine();
```

Also check the internet permission is added into manifest.XML

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```